# How do we use Javascript function in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am using `WordPress` social media plug-in. When any user clicks on icon it opens the link in new tab, but i want it in new window, so for this purpose i am using `Javascript` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
```

But the main problem is my code is written in PHP and i don't have any idea how to use javascript function in it. Here is my PHP function.

```
$out_button = array(
            'tag' => 'a',
            'class' => 'synved-social-button synved-social-button-' . $context .  ' synved-social-provider-' . $button_key . $class_extra,
            'data-provider' => $button_key,
            'target' => $button_key != 'mail' ? '_blank' : '',
            'rel' => 'nofollow',
            'title' => $title,
            'href' => $href,
            'child-list' => array(
                array(
                    'tag' => 'img',
                    'alt' => $button_key,
                    'class' => 'synved-share-image',
                    'width' => $size,
                    'style' => 'width:' . $size . 'px;' . $style,
                    'src' => $image_uri,
                )
            )
        );
```

`'href' => $href,` In this i have to write the `Javascript` function so any idea how can i do it.

Comment: actually this is no function. it is an array-structure definition.

Comment: helle yes i know its not function i just mistakenlly write it sory for that.
@billyonecan Its not working, it still open the link in new tab

Comment: still not working, Is that my javascript function is correct. I think its correct, but it not working don't the reason

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though your php array should be setting the target to _blank if the key isn't mail. If you just set

```
 'target' => '_blank',
```

does that give you your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an onclick event handler?

```
onclick = "Some_JavascriptFunction()"
```

then in javascript you can use `window.location.href = "someURL.php";`

Comment: why dont just use echo'<button onclick="Redirect()" href = "#">';
then this Redirect() function is your function you mentioned above that is working

Comment: This is plugin in, and the array they created is the part of that plugin in, so i don't want to change there code because i don't have permission to do that as well.